# Firebase android how to send verification email without sign in?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification()
```

I can send email verification like that. But how can I do this if I don't know currentUser because nobody signed in?

Is there any other way like you can send password reset email, where I don't need to use currentUser?

```
firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must be signed in if you want to send another verification email.  It's not possible to simply identify the user by email without signing them in.  This is a security measure meant to prevent someone from forcing verification emails to other people - it's expected that users must authorize the sending of their own verification email.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it is poor design if I ask the user password when clicks on the 'Resend email verification' button?

Comment: I don't have an opinion about that.  All I can tell you is how the API works.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't do that, email won't be send

in Kotlin `?` character means `not null`. if variable is `null` then method won't execute at all.

if you really need to call `sendEmailVerification()` then use `!!` instead of `?`, but it may crash when variable is `null` (and will in your not logged case)

Kotlin null-safety doc in [HERE](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Comment: I know it, but the question is there is know any other way like send password reset email, where I don't need to use currentUser?
firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)

Comment: The question doesn't really have anything to do with Kotlin null safety.  It's asking if there is a way to call sendVerificationEmail without a current user object (not call it on a null object).